# Synchronize two db from local to remote with Mysql Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Can you synchronize the data between two databases?

I have a local database and a remote, and I want the data is sent to the db remotely using mysql workbench.

How would this work?

Comment: possible duplicate to [How to synchronize database local and remote with Mysql Workbench?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287692/how-to-synchronize-database-local-and-remote-with-mysql-workbench?rq=1)

Comment: i have read that post but i don't have resolved

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved with `Toad` for `MySQL`. This tool compares the database and allows me to do the synchronization of the different rows.